# Is it correct to use "for" with "required"?

Tags: grammaticality

I am editing a sentence that is of the form:

> A has required for B to effect a change.

To my ear, this sounds better:

> A has required that B effect a change.

Am I wrong in my dislike of "has required for?"

Comment: Or "A has required B to effect a change" (where A and B are both clearly persons)?

Comment: _Require_ with an agent subject can take an infinitive complement with B-Raising. That means no _for_, since that's the mark of an unRaised subject: _A has required B to effect a change_ is grammatical. It can also take an untensed _that_-complement (what used to be called "the subjunctive"), but in this case the _that_ complementizer cannot be deleted: _A has required that B effect a change_ is OK, but not **A has required B effect a change.*

Comment: I'm not sure I would use "required" in this situation. Maybe "requested".

Comment: @MrLister: continued employment often depends on being duly sensitive to the distinction between what your employer *requests* and what your employer *requires* of you.

Comment: @John Lawler Some UK dialects include the *for*, as in 'I asked him for to tell me his name'. The Geordie dialect (North-east England, cities of Newcastle, Sunderland and surrounds) is full of it.

Comment: _Ask_ has different rules from _require_. For one thing, _ask_ has an indirect object and _require_ doesn't. So _ask_ can't take [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) like _require_ does; instead, it takes optional B-Equi. Keeping the _for_ part of the _for...to_ infinitive complementizer is a rural feature in the U.S, too. It shows up in old songs, for instance. Mostly _for_ is deleted when the infinitive's subject is moved or deleted, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wrong about anything, then it's about *merely* disliking this ungrammatical construction.

Whoever wrote that sentence clearly mixed up "A has required B to effect a change" (which expands to your fix) with "It is required for B to effect a change" (which expands to "It is required that B effect a change").

Now, having written this, I will try to double-check that this error hasn't already become grammatical...

Comment: Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason it sounds odd/unacceptable is the *for*. It sounds especially weird when only the past tense is involved:

I required for him to effect a change.

But without it, it sounds better

I required him to effect a change.

Your liking of the second likely stems from the fact that it is the mandative subjunctive:

I insisted that he *be* at the meeting.